# AND function in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, gantt-chart

I'm trying to create a new mesure in order to create a gantt chart, but the dax field keeps spitting that there's an error. Where in fact i literally copied the same code in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QugkBqc-jIs&t=184s) i'm following.

And the new mesure is as follows:

```
CF Gantt = 
var startdate =
CALCULATE(
    min(Contracts_range[Start Date ],
    REMOVEFILTERS(TabelaCalculada)
), var EndDate =
CALCULATE(
    min(Contracts_range[End Date]),
    REMOVEFILTERS(TabelaCalculada)

)
var ProjectPeriod =
    min(TabelaCalculada[Date]) >= startdate
    && min(TabelaCalculada[Date]) <=  startdate

var result =
if(
    TabelaCalculada,
    1
)
return
```

You see PBI is saying the following: "the syntax for '&&' is incorrect", i even searched the documentation for this particular AND method but i don't see how it's wrong.

Comment: you are using var incorrectly. It should be used only once per variable to define it. Instead of "var startdate", use just startdate.

Comment: too many syntax mistakes. What do you want to achieve with the measure?

Comment: @RADO
I actually didn't use var more than once the first time, i think you're referring to where i did repeat var twice for startdate. But even correcting that it didn't work. Now it says that the syntax for ')' is incorrect.

Comment: @Mik i need a measure that returns a 1 if i have a date that's either on or after the starting date and on or before the ending date.

Comment: Note that `min(TabelaCalculada[Date]) >= startdate  && min(TabelaCalculada[Date]) <=  startdate` can be simplified to `min(TabelaCalculada[Date]) = startdate`, so "&&" is not your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This DAX is invalid in multiple ways which I point out on the assumption that you are trying to learn what valid DAX is.

- Comma after the definition of var startdate.
- Project Period is a bunch of filters with no actual function.
- Project Period is trying to filter on an aggregate, which is not allowed.
- return statement is missing the return argument
- var result is incomprehensible.

This will return a 1 for each row where the date falls between minimum Start Date and maximum End Date, per your latest comment.

```
CF Gantt = 
    var startdate =
        CALCULATE(
            min(Contracts_range[Start Date]),
            REMOVEFILTERS(TabelaCalculada)
        )
    var EndDate =
        CALCULATE(
            max(Contracts_range[End Date]),
            REMOVEFILTERS(TabelaCalculada)    
        )
    var result = if(
        selectedvalue(TabelaCalculada[Date] >= startdate 
        && TabelaCalculada[Date] <= EndDate,1)
    )

return result
```

Comment: Let's see if OP has the skills to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @dani u thank you for replying! Now is giving only one syntax error for the startdate inside the var result. It says that the syintax for ")" is incorrect. And only the startdate has a red underline.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a third syntax alternative that worked. So my goal as i explained was to create a Gantt Chart using the matrix innate visual and for that one way to do it is to create a measure  that returns a 1 if i have a date that's either on or after the starting date and on or before the ending date.

```
BetweenDates = 

 VAR beginning = min ( Contracts_range[Start Date])

 VAR finish = max ( Contracts_range[End Date] )

 VAR duration = max ( Contracts_range[Duration] )

 VAR colorVar = 0
RETURN

SWITCH (

TRUE(),

AND ( MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) >= beginning ,  MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) <= finish ) && duration >0,1

)
```